# Is shared memory in POSIX protected against race conditions?

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory, race-condition

I have two processes written in C running on Linux that access shared memory.
Both processes have something along the lines of

```
int shm_fd = shm_open(NAME, O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(shm_data_struct));
struct shm_data_struct* shm_ptr = (struct shm_data_struct*)mmap(0, sizeof(struct shm_data_struct), PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
```

Both processes can read and write from the struct in shared memory.
My question is: does POSIX automatically provide any sort of protection from race conditions or do you always have to add in your own semaphore/mutex in this scenario?

Comment: You need something to synchronize access to it, yes.

Comment: Q: My question is does POSIX automatically provided any sort of protections from race conditions? A: No.  Q:  or do you always have to add in your own semaphore/mutex in this scenario?  A: If you need a lock, then a) you must decide the most appropriate mechanism yourself (semaphores are a Pop Favorite - but certainly not your only option), and b) apply it yourself.  Q: Think about it - do you WANT Posix to impose locking if you don't need it?  Or impose a "once-size-fits-all" default if there's a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use any library or system call to access the memory once it's set up. It's accessed directly by CPU instructions just like any other memory. That's because it *is* memory just like any other memory.

The memory in question is shared between threads in different processes. But the fact that the threads are in different processes is irrelevant. Everything that applies to sharing memory between threads in a single process applies the sharing memory between threads in different processes: You need memory barriers and some form of synchronization.

Comment: I agree 100%.  It's worth emphasizing, however, that just because you have "concurrency", you don't always NEED "mutual exclusion".

Comment: @paulsm4, Well, that's true if you have multiple readers. However, with a writer, you need mutual exclusion. But -- and I think this is what you meant -- you don't necessarily need a lock/mutex to achieve that exclusion. For example, a ring buffer with a single reader and single writer can be achieved without locks as long as you can write one of the buffers element's automatically. That is indeed why I said "some form of synchronization" rather than something more specific (but incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

> does POSIX automatically provide any sort of protection from race
> conditions or do you always have to add in your own semaphore/mutex in
> this scenario?

The kernel does not provide any process level locks to the shared memory. It has to be done in the application code. Normally, a binary semaphore is used for mutual exclusion, so that only one process (or thread, in case there is multi-threading,) accesses the shared memory at a time.